# audacity - convert multiple .aup's to .mp3's

Tags: mp3, music, c++, c, audacity

I have a bunch of about 130 .aup files (all recordings of vinyls) that I would like to convert to mp3. Each .aup is an entire side of the vinyl (I don't want to split the tracks - the whole side as one mp3 is fine). My problem is how can i batch convert all these aups to mp3s in one go. It would be very tedious to open each .aup one at a time then in the Apply Chain dialog: select 'Apply to Current Project' for 130 files..one by one.

Has anyone had any luck changing the code, or otherwise to come up with a solution?

I've traced it down to the below method in (BatchProcessDialog.cpp)

```
void BatchProcessDialog::OnApplyToProject(wxCommandEvent &event)
{
   long item = mChains->GetNextItem(-1,
                                    wxLIST_NEXT_ALL,
                                    wxLIST_STATE_SELECTED);
   if (item == -1) {
      wxMessageBox(_("No chain selected"));
      return;
   }
   wxString name = mChains->GetItemText(item);

   wxDialog d(this, wxID_ANY, GetTitle());
   ShuttleGui S(&d, eIsCreating);

   S.StartHorizontalLay(wxCENTER, false);
   {
      S.StartStatic(wxT(""), false);   // deliberately not translated (!)
      {
         S.SetBorder(20);
         S.AddFixedText(wxString::Format(_("Applying '%s' to current project"),
                                         name.c_str()));
      }
      S.EndStatic();
   }
   S.EndHorizontalLay();

   d.Layout();
   d.Fit();
   d.CenterOnScreen();
   d.Move(-1, 0);
   d.Show();
   Hide();

   wxWindowDisabler wd;

   gPrefs->Write(wxT("/Batch/ActiveChain"), name);

   mBatchCommands.ReadChain(name);
   if (!mBatchCommands.ApplyChain()) {
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to roll my own script in autohotkey (it is a bit unstable, but can get through a few files at a time):

```
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#p::Pause

#x::Exit

#a::
direc = C:\Documents and Settings\Test\My Documents\myaups\
FileList =  ; Initialize to be blank.
Loop, %direc%*.aup
    FileList = %FileList%%A_LoopFileName%`n
Loop, parse, FileList, `n
{
    Sleep 2500
    Run, "C:\Program Files\Audacity 1.3 Beta (Unicode)\audacity.exe"
    Sleep 2500
    WinWait, Audacity, 
    IfWinNotActive, Audacity, , WinActivate, Audacity, 
    WinWaitActive, Audacity,
    if A_LoopField =  ; Ignore the blank item at the end of the list.
        continue
    Sleep 2500
    Send, {CTRLDOWN}o{CTRLUP}
    Sleep 3000
    WinWait, Select one or more audio files..., 
    IfWinNotActive, Select one or more audio files..., , WinActivate, Select one or more audio files..., 
    WinWaitActive, Select one or more audio files..., 
    Sleep, 2800
    Send, %direc%
    Sleep, 2600
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 2600
    Send, %A_LoopField% ;filename from direc loop
    Sleep, 2600
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 4000
    IfWinActive, Warning - Opening Old Project File
    {
    Send, {Enter}
    Sleep, 1000
    }
    Sleep, 3800
    IfWinActive, Warning - Orphan Block File(s)
    {
    Send {Tab}
    Sleep 1000
    Send {Tab}
    Sleep 1000
    Send, {Enter}
    }
    Sleep, 3000
    Send, {SHIFTDOWN}c{SHIFTUP} ;first must set the keyboard shortcut in audacity to Shift+C
    Sleep, 3600
    WinWait, Apply Chain, 
    IfWinNotActive, Apply Chain, , WinActivate, Apply Chain, 
    WinWaitActive, Apply Chain, 
    Sleep 500
    Send, {TAB}{ENTER}
    Sleep 4000
    Loop ;wait till conversion finishes
    {
        if !WinExist("Apply Chain")
            break  ; Terminate the loop
        else
            Sleep 200
    }
    Sleep 3800
    Send, {CTRLDOWN}q{CTRLUP} ;exit audacity
    Sleep, 3800
    WinWait, Save changes?, 
    IfWinNotActive, Save changes?, , WinActivate, Save changes?, 
    WinWaitActive, Save changes?, 
    Sleep 500
    Send, {TAB}{ENTER}
    Sleep 6500
}
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

It's going to be somewhat tricky if you don't have C++ knowledge, as you need to know about the class structure of which the `mChains` object is instantiated from and call the right functions to chain it.

An alternative might be to script something using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) which emulates the GUI clicks for you.

Comment: I took your idea about automating GUI clicks

Answer (score 0):

Audacity (at least recent versions) has in the dialogue from <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Apply Chain...</kbd> the button  <kbd>Apply to Files...</kbd>  which allows to apply the chain to multiple files at once.